# Exclude specific file types from Visual Studio search

Tags: visual-studio

In [Google ProtoBuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) there are many generated files that having file name like *.pb.h and *.pb.cc

When I use Visual Studio to search this type of project, it seems there is no option to exclude certain types, like `find . |grep -v pb.cc|xargs grep ABC`. And I don't want to exclude those generated files from my solution, as it might be good to have a look at what's generated.

One way I can think of is to use "Display file name only" option in Find dialog, and walk though all files to locate the files that are not generated:

```
D:\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\wrappers.pb.h
D:\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\any.pb.cc
D:\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\api.pb.cc
D:\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\cpp\cpp_message.cc <--
D:\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\descriptor.pb.cc
D:\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\duration.pb.cc
D:\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\empty.pb.cc
D:\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\extension_set_heavy.cc <--
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe an extension?